# With Social Meta Tag firebase dynamic link redirection is failing

Tags: android, firebase, linkedin-api, share, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm creating firebase dynamic link in android app by Firebase Dynamic Link sdk, Dynamic link include Social Meta Tag data (title, Description & image url). Generated link working fine from many platforms(facebook, whatsapp, insta, twitter, slack) but the preview link at LINKEDIN private chat redirecting user to the linkedin blank white screen.

clicking on preview part(red circle in screen shot) in linkedin chat redirecting user to blank white screen.
wrong redirection link:

https://appiskey.page.link/s?socialDescription=Hammad+Custom+Deal&socialImageUrl=https://dev-flashdash.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/deals/61541f613f268.png&socialTitle=Hammad+Custom+Deal+NZ

clicking on blue link part(green in screenshot) redirect user to my app which is happy flow.

link which redirection is correct:
https://appiskey.page.link/utZ8HGaGYFrABcT56

[image: linkedin chat screenshot with dynamic link]

Link Generation Android Code:

```
 Firebase.dynamicLinks.shortLinkAsync {
        link = myUri
        domainUriPrefix = BuildConfig.DYNAMIC_LINK_DOMAIN
        socialMetaTagParameters {
            description = deal.description ?: ""
            title = deal.name ?: ""
            imageUrl = deal.image?.toUri() ?: "".toUri()
        }
        androidParameters(BuildConfig.application_id) {

        }
        iosParameters(iosBundle) {
            appStoreId = Constants.IOS_STORE_ID
        }

    }.addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        hideLoader()
        _all_deals_event.value = BaseEvent(AllDealsEvents.ShareLink(result.shortLink.toString()))
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        hideLoader()
        showToast("Something went wrong.")
    }.toString()
```

Comment: I am struck with the same issue on LinkedIn, However it works fine on Facebook. Did you  get a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

just need to edit Link preview
go the the dynamic link and change it
Set up your short URL link
Customize your short link URL to make it more professional and contextual. Learn More

Link preview